# Extract multiple occurrences in the same line of a string between two delimiters

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

This one is tricky...  input has multiple occurrences per line over several lines.  many "id=" lines exist, but I only want ones starting with ai-c " id="

Example input (two long lines):

```
d-fl ai-c" id="3af3a73f26a63a-list-" lima zulu bravo hotel d-fl ai-c" id="7ab8273f273e7273f82c2-list-" alpha id="8372364fa2361ab1-list-" hotel foxtrox mike d-fl ai-c" id="973a72b72c72df12a2-list-" uniform hotel
```

start of second line golf november d-fl ai-c" id="83hd826ab712cc71-list-" bravo mike mike d-fl ai-c" id="7612364bab72a-list-" golf mike

Output desired is:

```
id="3af3a73f26a63a"

id="7ab8273f273e7273f82c2"

id="973a72b72c72df12a2"

id="83hd826ab712cc71"

id="7612364bab72a"
```

All of the script examples I've seen only seem to work for the first occurrence in a line.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is:

```
grep -oP '\hai-c"\h\Kid="[^-]*'  input.file | sed -e 's/$/"/'
```

Where we use `GNU grep` with the `Perl` feature turned on and the `-o` option to output just the matche(s), rather than the default whole line when a match is found.

**Output:**

```
id="3af3a73f26a63a"
id="7ab8273f273e7273f82c2"
id="973a72b72c72df12a2"
id="83hd826ab712cc71"
id="7612364bab72a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
sed ' s/d-fl ai-c" /\n/g; s/-/"\n/g; :L; /^id=/ P; D; bL; ' file
id="3af3a73f26a63a"
id="7ab8273f273e7273f82c2"
id="973a72b72c72df12a2"
id="83hd826ab712cc71"
id="7612364bab72a"
```